# jQuery - sort DIVs by className

Tags: jquery

I have a list of DIVs, like this :

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="cat1-4.2"><div>4</div></div>
    <div class="cat3-3.3"><div>3</div></div>
    <div class="cat2-5.1"><div>5</div></div>
    <div class="cat3-1.5"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="cat3-2.4"><div>2</div></div>
</div>
```

and I want to sort them, using jQuery

Server-side, I can define the wanted order, and include this order in the class names :

catX-**4.2**

I want to be able to call either the first order (in my example this DIV will be in the 4th position), or the second order (it will be in the 2nd position) : that explains the "4.2"

So if I call `OrderDIV(1)` I will have this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and if I call `OrderDIV(2)` I will have this :

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

(I will need to add more orders, like : catX-4.2.5.6.2)

Thank you VERY MUCH for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You changed the requirements mid way ... just like a true client.  Updated version with some comments attached.  Just to confirm, there are two "configurable" variables at the front.

classPrefix: the "prefix" unique to the class used to determine sort order ('cat' in this case)
listElementSelector: the jQuery selector used to obtain the list to sort.

```
function OrderDIV(position)
{
    var classPrefix = 'cat';
    var listElementSelector = '#list';

    // -- Decrement the position to make it 0 based
    position--;

    // -- Parses the "position" section from the given classes, and
    //    then the position at the specific index requested.
    var parsePosition = function(classes, pos) {
        // -- Split the "classes" into an array.
        var classList = classes.split(' ');

        // -- Determine which of the "classes" starts with the prefix we want.
        for( var i in classList )
        {
            if( classList[i].substr(0, classPrefix.length) == classPrefix )
            {
                // -- Strip out the positions section, and split it.
                var positions = classList[i].split('-')[1].split('.');

                // -- return the one position we want
                return positions[pos];
            }
        }

        // -- In the event that we don't find the class we're looking for ...
        return -1;
    }

    // -- Compares div A to div B, and returns an indicator of the order
    var funcSort = function(a, b) {
        // -- Use "parsePosition" to determine the sortable criteria from the classes.
       var compA = parsePosition($(a).attr('class'), position);
       var compB = parsePosition($(b).attr('class'), position);
       return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    };

    // -- Select the list element.
    var list = $(listElementSelector);

    // -- Select the list items, and return them as an array.
    var listitems = list.children('div').get();

    // -- Sort the array using the "funcSort".
    listitems.sort(funcSort);

    // -- Go through each of the array entries, and "append" them to the list container
    //   (this moves them to the 'back' of the list)
    $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { list.append(itm); });
}
```

Comment: seems perfect! Can you add some comments so I can try to understand what you've done? (THANK YOU VERY MUCH)

Comment: is it possible to adapt your code so I can add other classes to the DIVs ? like `<div class="class1 class2 SORT-4.2"><div>4</div></div>
`

Comment: I've updated the method and added some comments ... but try not to change the requirements mid-way ... ID was much easier to use than class in this context :P

Comment: This is a great answer except for one problem, it doesn't handle numbers larger than 9. If you have cat1-1.1 through cat1-10.10 you end up sorting them with 10 right after 1. To fix it, change line 24 to: return Number(positions[pos]);

Answer (score 5):

jQuery abstracts the `Array.prototype.sort()` method so you can use it on wrapped sets:

```
var OrderDIV = function(asc) {
    $('div#list').children().detach().sort(function(a,b) {
        return asc ? (+a.textContent) - (+b.textContent) : (+b.textContent) - (+a.textContent);
    }).appendTo(document.body);
}

OrderDIV(0);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.et/Ls2kd/9/

For simplicity I ordered the `<div>` nodes by their content. If you need to use the `ID` it shouldn't be a problem at all. Just access `a.id` and strip out the part you need for comparison (regex for instance).

Another thing to mention, InternetExplorer isn't aware of `.textContent` therefore should it be `a.textContent || a.text`.

Comment: That is not what author wants. Author wants to extract numeric value from `className`.

Comment: Or from `id`. And the argument should be numeric, not boolean (there can be more than 2 sets of sort indexes).

Comment: oops sorry, my mistake, i want to extract numeric value from className, not ID, sorry...

Comment: @artyom.stv: well, I mentioned that this is a simple example, but imo this is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: thank you for your help, I must admit I am a total newbie with jQuery, what would be the full code ? jsfiddle would be GREAT

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){

    var sort = [].sort;

    return function(comparator, getSortable) {

        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};

        var placements = this.map(function(){

            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing its original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );

            return function() {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }

                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

            };

        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });

    };

})();
```

Use this sort criteria for your needs:

```
function sortCriteria(k) {
    var regex = /\b\d+/g;
    return function(a, b){
        return parseInt(a.id.match(regex)[k]) > parseInt(b.id.match(regex)[k]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

$("#list >").sortElements(sortCriteria(0));
```

Comment: always use a radix value for `parseInt()`, beyond that I believe this is complete overkill.

Comment: seems interesting but I can't make it work : [http://jsfiddle.net/WFKNE/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/WFKNE/1/)

Comment: @jrm - because you have changed `id` to `class` in your html code with no changes in javascript. Change `a.id` and `b.id` to `a.className` and `b.className` in `function sortCriteria(k)` :)

Comment: Strange... It works on my computer well. That is an issue of jsfiddle.net I think