# How to sort <ul><li>'s based on class with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a TODO list app with an Unordered list. Within it I have a few list items. The li classes are high,medium,low. I would like li's with the class high to be placed before li's with the class medium and last ones with low.

```
<ul id="tasks">
  <li id="item3" class="priority low"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item3')"></a><span>This is a low priority task</span></li>
  <li id="item4" class="priority high"><></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item4')"></a><span>This is a high priority task</span></li>
  <li id="item5" class="priority low"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item5')"></a><span>This is another Low</span></li>
  <li id="item7" class="priority medium"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item7')"></a><span>And now a Medium</span></li>
</ul>
```

So the li with id of item4 should be first and then it should be item7 and then the li's with class low after.

Comment: Is php an option? Because then it would be real easy..

Comment: Why they are generated unordered at first place? Like, where it comes from? db? file? hardcoded html?

Comment: Someone had a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076844/jquery-sort-divs-by-classname

Comment: And is jQuery an option?

Comment: jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eAnJm/ (**5 lines of code**)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That seems like the best solution.

Comment: @elclanrs We don't yet know if OP is using jQuery...

Comment: I can go the route of jQuery, Im in the process of learning jscript and jQuery. So was just wondering if it was possible with pure javascript.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas—if speed matters, plain js is [very much faster](http://jsperf.com/sortelementlist).

Comment: @RobG I really don't think that the performance of well written jQuery code is ever an issue. Jumping to pure JS for performance reasons is senseless, IMO.

Comment: @user1792879 The API provided by a library like jQuery is far superior to the native browser API. A library also takes care of cross-browser incompatibilities. For learning purposes, you're welcome to experiment with pure JS, but when writing actual web-apps, I strongly recommend a library.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas—Unfortunately there's as much badly written jQuery as badly written anything. But it's worth pointing out the major pros and cons of any particular solution, the OP might be happy with performance sorting 5 elements, but not 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure JS version of @ŠimeVidas jQuery solution.

```
var tasks = document.querySelector('#tasks'),
    items = document.querySelectorAll('#tasks > li');

for (var i = 0, arr = ['high', 'medium', 'low']; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        if (~(" " + items[j].className + " ").indexOf(" " + arr[i] + " "))
            tasks.appendChild(items[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the best disguised bubble sort I've seen in quite some time! How does it perform with large lists? Cool use of `~`, much prettier than `<= -1`, but you can use `~items[j].className.indexOf(arr[i])` to be more concise. :-)

Comment: @RobG: ŠimeVidas gets the credit for the concept. I do like the `~` trick, but there's something to be said for the clarity of `> -1`. And you're right, it could be more concise since there's no chance of false positives here.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That's nice too, just a quick shim for the `.forEach()`. The `.slice()` won't work in IE8, but that's not hard to work around. :)

Comment: @RobG I expect performance issues with large lists, since the `tasks` element is not detached (from the DOM) during the process, so each `.appendChild()` triggers a page re-flow.

Comment: @user1689607 Yes, I always forget what that IE-workaround is `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use jQuery, and assuming your list is not very big, and assuming you've only got these three fixed types with no plans on changing this, I'd probably just dump the whole set into memory, clear out the list, then put them back in the list in order. Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var i;
    var items = jQuery("#tasks li");
    var lowItems = [];
    var medItems = [];
    var highItems = [];
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var jqItem = jQuery(items[i]);
        if (jqItem.hasClass("low")) lowItems.push(jqItem);
        if (jqItem.hasClass("medium")) medItems.push(jqItem);
        if (jqItem.hasClass("high")) highItems.push(jqItem);
    }
    var tasks = jQuery("#tasks");
    tasks.html("");
    for (i = 0; i < highItems.length; ++i) {
        tasks.append(highItems[i]);
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < medItems.length; ++i) {
        tasks.append(medItems[i]);
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < lowItems.length; ++i) {
        tasks.append(lowItems[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Šime Vidas's jsfiddle answer looks like it does the same thing in a much shorter and cleaner fashion, so I'd probably do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var sorter = [],
        tasks = $('#tasks');
    $('li.priority').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            priority = $this.hasClass('high') ? 3 : ($this.hasClass('medium') ? 2 : 1);
        sorter.push({
            el : this,
            priority : priority
        });
    }).detach();

    sorter.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.priority - b.priority;
    });

    $.each(sorter, function(){
        tasks.append(this.el);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With no jquery:

```
<ul id="tasks">
 <li id="item3" class="priority low"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item3')"></a><span>This is a low priority task</span></li>
 <li id="item4" class="priority high"><></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item4')"></a><span>This is a high priority task</span></li>
 <li id="item5" class="priority low"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item5')"></a><span>This is another Low</span></li>
 <li id="item7" class="priority medium"><span></span><a href="#" class="closex" onclick="removeItem('item7')"></a><span>And now a Medium</span></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tasks = document.getElementById("tasks");
var liElements = tasks.getElementsByTagName("li");
var lowPriority = [];
var mediumPriority = [];
var highPriority = [];
var removal = [];
for (var i = 0, len = liElements.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (liElements[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("low") > -1) lowPriority.push(liElements[i].cloneNode(true));
    if (liElements[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("medium") > -1) mediumPriority.push(liElements[i].cloneNode(true));
    if (liElements[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("high") > -1) highPriority.push(liElements[i].cloneNode(true));
    removal.push(liElements[i]);
}

for (var i = 0, len = removal.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var liItem = removal[i];
    liItem.parentNode.removeChild(liItem);
}

for( var i = 0, len = lowPriority.length; i < len; i++){
    tasks.appendChild(lowPriority[i]);
}
for (var i = 0, len = mediumPriority.length; i < len; i++) {
    tasks.appendChild(mediumPriority[i]);
}
for (var i = 0, len = highPriority.length; i < len; i++) {
    tasks.appendChild(highPriority[i]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another jQuery–less option:

```
// Just a helper
function toArray(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=obj.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return result;
}

// Uses querySelectorAll, but could use getElementsByTagName instead
function sortByPriority(id) {
  var nodes;
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  if (el) { 
    nodes = toArray(el.querySelectorAll('li.priority'));
    nodes.sort(function(a, b) {
      function getIndex(el) {
        return el.className.indexOf('low') != -1? 1 : 
               el.className.indexOf('medium') != -1? 2 :
               el.className.indexOf('high') != -1? 3 :
               0; // default
      }
      return getIndex(b) - getIndex(a);
    });

    for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      el.appendChild(nodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

It uses a few more lines that a jQuery (or perhaps any library) based solution but you don't have to load several thousand lines of library either.

Also, this runs about 5 times faster in Firefox and IE 9 and 10 times faster in Chrome than a jQuery solution (see http://jsperf.com/sortelementlist).

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript, and simple code!

```
var tasks = document.getElementById("tasks");
var lis = tasks.getElementsByTagName("li");
var lisarr = Array.prototype.slice.call(lis);

var priority = function(e){
    var prio = {low: 0, medium: 1, high: 2};
    return prio[e.getAttribute("class").match(/low|high|medium/)[0]];
};

lisarr.sort(function(a,b){
    var ap = priority(a), bp = priority(b);
    return bp - ap;
});

tasks.innerHTML = lisarr.reduce(function(prev, current){
    return prev + current.outerHTML;
}, '');
```

Comment: A couple of things that should  be noted: there may be child LIs that aren't immediate child nodes of the UL and should not be sorted with the rest; treating host objects like native objects (`Array.prototype.slice.call(lis)`) will throw errors in some browsers (IE < 8 at least); outerHTML is not well supported; `.reduce` is an ES5 method so not supported by older browsers. But otherwise, neat. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is not the best solution for older browsers.