# Best way to sort elements by an integer value through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements ordered like this :

```
<div class="item pix-txt medium">
   <span class="animated jumbo bold" data-sequence="5" data-entrance="fade" data-exit="fade" data-top="50" data-left="-150">Masters of the Internet</span> 
   <span class="animated medium" data-sequence="3" data-entrance="fade" data-exit="fade">
   <span class="animated medium" data-sequence="2" data-entrance="fade" data-exit="fade"></span>

</div>
```

Each `.animated` span has a `data-sequence` with an integer attached to it. What is the best way to sort these elements in a javascript Array by `data-sequence` value?

Comment: You can find an answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076844/jquery-sort-divs-by-classname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort them in a JavaScript array, but *not* sort the DOM, you can do this;

```
var ar = $('.item').children().get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('sequence') - $(b).data('sequence');
});
```

This turns the jQuery object into an Array using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get), and then uses the [`Array` `sort()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Note `ar` will be a JavaScript array, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks @Matt ! but a little question with the logic. Why do we subtract a's sequence to b's sequence?

Comment: @AJ: the sort function must return < 0 if "a" is to be earlier than "b" in the sort order, 0 if they're equal, and > 1 if "a" should be after "b". The "-" is a easy way to do that if the sort value is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JS solution. You may have to adjust the selector part to your needs.

```
function sortElementsByAttribute(selector, attribute) {
    // Fetch all elements matching the selector, and convert it to an Array from a NodeList
    var elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));

    // `sort` sorts inplace
    elements.sort(function (n1, n2) {
        // convert `attribute` attribute to integers, and sort the elements by that.
        return parseInt(n1.getAttribute(attribute), 10) - parseInt(n2.getAttribute(attribute), 10);
    });

    // Loop through the sorted elements
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var node = elements[i];
        // This would move the `node` to be the last child of its parent node,
        // basically sorting the elements
        node.parentNode.appendChild(node);
    }
}

sortElementsByAttribute(".item span", "data-sequence");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QssyK/