# sort div class by name jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, sorting, html

which is the shortest and best way to sort div class by name not by alphabetic name.

Here is my Testsite:

http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview_test.html

I will to sort in the content div class so:

1. div class="dark_red_gradient"
2. div class="red_gradient"
3. div class="orange_gradient"
4. div class="yellow_gradient"
5. div class="white_gradient"

How can i solve this? I know i can to give my class dark_red_1 but i will solve this without that.

I hope someone have idea.

Comment: what do you mean not by alphabet name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - sort DIVs by className](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5076844/1612146)

Comment: How would you like to sort them, if not alphabetical?

Comment: i mean to sort not by alphabetic

Comment: @Johan i whould  like to sort so:
first->div class="dark_red_gradient"
second->div class="red_gradient"
..div class="orange_gradient"
..div class="yellow_gradient"
..div class="white_gradient"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var array = ['dark_red_gradient', 'red_gradient', 'orange_gradient', 'yellow_gradient', 'white_gradient'];

var $ul = $('#mytest');
var sorted = $ul.children('li').get().sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return $.inArray(o1.className, array) - $.inArray(o2.className, array)
});
$.each(sorted, function () {
    $(this).appendTo($ul)
});
```

Assuming `mytest` is the id of the container `li` element.

Comment: @Dave-88 did you add the `id` to the `ul` also you need to do it in dom ready.... also is your test site updated with this changes

Comment: Yes i do it in dom ready the code is update in report-overview.js

Comment: @Dave-88 still the `ul` element does not have the `id`